# Measuring tilt with left, right, forward and backward in ios

Tags: ios, cmmotionmanager

I want to find tilt in all side (left, right, forward, backward)

I have use below code to find left and right

```
[motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *deviceMotion, NSError *error)
        {
            if (deviceMotion.attitude.roll <= -1)
            {
                [self TiltControl:@"left"];
            }
            else if(deviceMotion.attitude.roll > 1)
            {
                [self TiltControl:@"right"];
            }
        }];
```

now how can find forward and backward...

what is the best way to find all 4 tilt...

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `attitude.pitch` property:

```
if(deviceMotion.attitude.pitch > 0 ) {
    NSLog(@"forward");
}
else if(deviceMotion.attitude.pitch < 0) {
    NSLog(@"backward");
}
```

There is also rotation around Z axis, available as `attitude.yaw`. Credits to [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/cmdevicemotion/).

Comment: ciuba: its not working friend... it always shows "forward" & i think default pitch value shows 1.6 and its never come -ve value.

Comment: What is the phone's position, is it laying on a table? In this case the pitch value won't change. Also you can try changing the conditions  `deviceMotion.attitude.pitch > 0` if they're not suitable for your needs.